Why there is two different answers for the volume of a frustum?
Here is the problem:
A margarine tub has the shape of the frustum of a cone. With the lower base having diameter length 11 cm and the upper base having diameter length 14 cm, the volume of such a container 6 ⅔ cm tall can be determined by using H = 32 ⅔ cm, and h = 26 cm. Find its volume.
Let
R = ¹⁴⁄₂ = 7
r = ¹¹⁄₂ = 5.5
H = 32 ⅔ cm
h = 26 cm
k = H - h = 6 ⅔
So the solution in the book is using the formula
V = ⅓πR²H - ⅓πr²h
Which is derived from this image:

doing so we have
V = ⅓ π (7 cm)² (32 ⅔ cm) - ⅓ π (5.5 cm)² (26 cm)
V ≈ 852.593 cm³
To check, I used the other formula:
V = ⅓πk (R² + Rr + r²) ; wherein k = H - h
and the result is
V ≈ 822.050 cm³
Why there are different answers, where does the error came from?

"Frustum", not "frustRum", by the way.

Indeed, the word is frustratingly easy to misspell.

The difference comes from the inconsistent information in the question:

$\dfrac{d}{D}=\dfrac{11}{14}\approx 0.7857$

$\dfrac{h}{H}=\dfrac{26}{32+\frac23}\approx 0.7723$


If instead you used $h=\frac{11}{3}(6+\frac23)=24+\frac49$ and $H=\frac{14}{3}(6+\frac23)=31+\frac19$ then you would again get $V \approx 822.050$, and consistent answers.

Does it mean that the cone doesn't "converge" where it should?

@EricDuminil It does not "converge" where the question suggests.
